# How can I make Microsoft Teams show URL previews from a webhook?

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

When I post a URL as a user, Teams automatically [unfurls](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#unfurling) it to show a preview:

[image: URL unfurling in Microsoft Teams]

When a webhook does the same thing, the URL remains plaintext:

[image: URL posted by a webhook in Microsoft Teams]

Can I make Teams show a URL preview instead?

I've checked the [Office 365 Connectors API Reference](https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/Reference) but don't see any mention of this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL-preview is not yet supported for links from connectors.

Comment: I've added a feature request to the Microsoft Teams customer feedback website: [Show URL previews for messages from Connectors](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/suggestions/16954903)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a clickable link :

```
[Clickable link to google](http://google.fr)
```

Though, it doesn't preview the URL, I believe.

Comment: I tried making a link like this, and it showed the preview, but didn't collapse the link